# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax, SQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    CREATE TABLE [jplist].[Item](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Image] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [Likes] [int] NULL,
    [Keyword1] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Keyword2] [varchar](150) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];


mysql error : 

    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[jplist].[Item](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](150) NUL' at line 1
```

i can't found any error

Comment: I've never seen using square brackets instead of `"`

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to post your actual PHP code - as what you have doesn't make PHP sense :)

Comment: Square bracket identifiers only work in SQL Server or SQLite IIRC. MySQL requires standard backtick quoting for tables/column names.

Comment: is it mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [jplist].[Item](
[ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Title] varchar(150) NULL,
[Image] varchar(150) NULL,
[Description] varchar(MAX) NULL,
[Likes] int NULL,
[Keyword1] varchar(150) NULL,
[Keyword2] varchar(150) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
```

You should avoid using `[]` around datatypes.